# SpaceNavigator settings menu in SketchUp

Tags: sketchup

Can anyone tell me how to access the Space Navigator's settings inside SketchUp 8?  I want to switch to helicopter mode, which is shown in the screenshot of the menu which is shown in the dialog that comes up when I start SketchUp, but since I upgraded to SketchUp 8 I haven't been able to actually get to this menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed tech support a couple times and figured out what happened.  There should be a button mapping option labeled `Popup Menu`.  There used to be a toolbar, but now the only way to access these features is by mapping the popup menu to one of the Space Navigator's buttons.

When I upgraded SketchUp, the new button mapping options did not appear in my config profile.  I had to delete my old settings and create a new config before I could map the button so I could access the menu.